# Castle DynamicProxy (or other AOP system) with Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, castle-dynamicproxy

Is there a way to use Castle DynamicProxy interceptors with EF entities, like the ByteCode providers in NH?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. EF always uses its own dynamic proxy implementation and it doesn't have extension hooks to change this implementation.